# Dart - Print value from Object Array in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an object array which says [Instance of 'OrderItems', Instance of 'OrderItems', Instance of 'OrderItems', Instance of 'OrderItems'] where 'OrderItems' is the class name. That class has three variables name,price,color. I need to parse through all of the object inside the array and should print name of all the items. I have the value as json string, i decode it using

```
List<OrderItems> parseOrderItems(String orderItemsString) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(orderItemsString).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<OrderItems>((json) => OrderItems.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<OrderItems>> fetchOrderItems( String orderItemsString) async {
    String orderItems = orderItemsString;
    return compute(parseOrderItems, orderItems);
  }
```

Now i access it using futurebuilder like below::

```
FutureBuilder(
                                        future: fetchOrderItems(orderData['order']),
                                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                          return Center(
                                            child:Text("${snapshot.error}"),
                                          );
                                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                          return Text(snapshot.data!.toString);
                                        } else {
                                          return const Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                          );
                                        }
                                      },)
```

The snapshot.data!.tostring() prints ['Instance of OrderItems', Instance of 'OrderItems']. Now instead of snapshot.data!.toString() i need to print every object's name value. snapshot.data!.length says length is not defined for object. but snapshot.data!.runtimeType returns List. What's this irony?

Answer (score 0):

Create the model class of OrderItems using online json to dart (Google it )
then map your values into the Model class, if you want to access/Print the single value present inside the model object then use the index value of object.

this.OrderItems.name
or
this.OrderItems[0].name

Answer (score 0):

Your `snapshot.data` is a list of instances of your OrderItems. I recommend using a `ListView.builder`  or `ListView.seperated` to loop through each item in the list and render the data.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/listview-builder-in-flutter/

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html

Try this:

```
else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 30.0,
                  );
                },
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
               // or return Text(snapshot.data[index].to_s); 
                return Text(snapshot.data[index].name);
              });
    }
```

Comment: Using foreach says that the method 'forEach' isn't defined for type Object

Comment: forEach is called on the list holding your items, the (i) in for each represents an individual index of the list, an anonymous method is then called on each specific index.

Comment: I have updated the full code. Can you please explain what to do. I'm new to flutter

Comment: When you said print I thought you were referring to printing to the console.

Comment: Leave the ui part i can manage to do that... I need to print value from snapshot.data! Which returns object

Comment: itemcount: snapshot.data.length - length is not defined for Object